# How to Insert ajax data into table in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the ajax code that takes the data in json and creates a table with the data. But I'm getting this error:

**parsererror**

```html
$('#loadddx').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'), // Example: ajax.php?id=
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resp) {
            var trHTML = '';
            $.each(resp, function(i, userData) {
                for (i = 0; i < resp.userData.length; i++) {
                    trHTML +=
                        '<tr><td>' +
                        resp.userData[i].pais +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        resp.userData[i].data +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        resp.userData[i].origem +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        resp.userData[i].ip +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        resp.userData[i].isp +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        resp.userData[i].browser +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        resp.userData[i].os +
                        resp.userData[i].newid +
                        '</td></tr>';
                }
            });
            $('#result').append(trHTML);

            console.log(resp);
            $("#showDataa").modal("show");

        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the .php file that returns the data

```html
$res = [];
while ($stmt - > fetch()) {
$res[] = array("success" => true, "pais" => $pais, "data" => $data, "origem" => $origem, "ip" => $ip, "isp" => $isp, "browser" => $browser, "os" => $os, "newid" => $newid);
echo json_encode($res);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In the network tab of your developer tools (press F12) What does the content of the request look like? I think you are not returning json. You can also add `debugger` statement in JavaScript and your code will be paused so you can inspect the result or `console.log(resp)`

Comment: Is it typo `resp.UserData` should be `resp.userData`

Comment: You also can't echo an array

Comment: @user2486 I changed but the error continues, i change the post

Comment: Your updated post doesn't include the change @user2486 suggested you should make. Change `for (i = 0; i < resp.UserData.length; i++) {` to `for (i = 0; i < resp.userData.length; i++) {`

Comment: @WillCraig i edited the post, i'm getting **parsererror** now

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your PHP as follows:

```
$stmt->fetch();
echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "pais" => $pais, "data" => $data, "origem" => $origem, "ip" => $ip, "isp" => $isp, "browser" => $browser, "os" => $os, "newid" => $newid));
```

Not sure what the `while` loop was for? If the values within the loop are globals being updated by `$stmt->fetch()` each iteration and you need multiple iterations try the following:

```
$res = [];
while($stmt->fetch()) $res[] = array("success" => true, "pais" => $pais, "data" => $data, "origem" => $origem, "ip" => $ip, "isp" => $isp, "browser" => $browser, "os" => $os, "newid" => $newid);
echo json_encode($res);
```

### UPDATE

Update your JS as follows, assuming you used the first PHP example I gave you. Not sure the way you are appending your table rows is the best, but this should resolve your issue. If it doesn't please provide the console.log output for resp:

```js
$('#loadddx').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'), // Example: ajax.php?id=
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resp) {
           console.log(resp);
           
           $('#result').append(
             '<tr><td>' +
             resp.pais +
             '</td><td>' +
             resp.data +
             '</td><td>' +
             resp.origem +
             '</td><td>' +
             resp.ip +
             '</td><td>' +
             resp.isp +
             '</td><td>' +
             resp.browser +
             '</td><td>' +
             resp.os +
             resp.newid +
             '</td></tr>';
           }

           $("#showDataa").modal("show");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you also changed `resp.UserData.length` to `resp.userData.length`?

Comment: yes, i changed and i got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in `for (i = 0; i < resp.userData.length; i++) `

Comment: @NathanSilva - I have updated my answer to include some JS. If this doesn't resolve the issue for you please provide the output from console for `console.log(resp)`. I suspect `resp.userData` needs to be `resp.data` looking at your PHP

Comment: I still getting **parsererror** in `console.log(status);` I didn't understand why

Comment: @NathanSilva - Is the href of anchor with ID of 'loadddx' pointing to the correct endpoint? In other words the PHP provided. Parsererror would indicate the response is not valid JSON. Remove the `dataType: 'json'` line and provide the console log output for `resp`. This will stop jQuery trying to parse the JSON so we can see the raw AJAX response.

Comment: I removed and i got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.success (analisar.php?data=2017-10-03:256)
    at j (jquery.js:3099)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3211)
    at x (jquery.js:8264)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:8605)` in `for (i = 0; i < resp.userData.length; i++) {`

Comment: @NathanSilva - I just noticed data field is a column in the table, not an array of data for the table row! I have updated my answer with some updated JS which should hopefully do the job!